# Using co-factor expansion, how can i prove that $ Det(E_i) = Det(E_{i-1}) - Det(E_{i-2}) $?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

Okay so I am not exactly sure how to answer the question the way it wants me to.... for instance.. the determinant for E1=1 and E2=0 and for E3= -1 which satisfies the formula it wants me to prove for part a... but just showing an instance would not suffice in proving the formula so how can i go about it in a more general manner?

Comment: you know the formula of determinant by going thru a row or a column? Just go thru the first row.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean?? yes i know how to get the determinant but what does that have to do with part a of the question?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to denote by $\overline{(E_n)_{1,1}}$ the $i,j$ minor of $E_n$. In general, you can define $E_n$ as an $n\times n$ matrix such that $(E_n)_{i,j}=1$ if and only if $|i-j|<2.$ So just the $3$ inner diagonals survive. So, consider then the determinant (laplace expansion) of $E_n$ from the first row
$$det(E_n)=\sum _{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}(E_n)_{1,1}det(\overline{(E_n)_{1,n}})= det(\overline{(E_n)_{1,1}})-det(\overline{(E_n)_{1,2}})$$
notice that $\overline{(E_n)_{1,1}}=E_{n-1}$ and $\overline{(E_n)_{1,2}}$ has a unique $1$ in the first column, so you can also eliminate the first column(again by the Laplace expansion of the determinant) show that this matrix that results is $E_{n-2}$ **Hint:** Check that you are basically eliminating the first two rows and columns of the original matrix.